# Is at appropriate to talk about "standard deviations" from a mean?

Tags: statistics

I have a rather large set of survey responses.  These are a subset of an even larger set that covers our entire enterprise.  Several hundred thousand individuals took the survey, of which ~11,000 are in my organization.

Individual responses to the questions are Positive/Neutral/Negative.  What I have  is the percentage that chose each category by office for all offices with greater than 10 people.  There are 226 offices.  So I have something like:

```
Question 1:
Office 1 -- Suborg 1 -- 10 people -- 50% positive/25% neutral/25% negative
Office 2 -- Suborg 4 -- 47 people -- 30% positive/40% neutral/30% negative
...
Office 226 -- Suborg 3 -- 1135 people -- 47% positive/25% neutral/28% negative
```

Our parent organization provided a basic analysis that shows how our organization compared to the enterprise-wide average in terms of positive response rate to each of the questions.  They highlighted instances in which our average was "more than two standard deviations from the mean".

What I've been asked to do is take the responses for our 226 offices and aggregate them across 5 sub-organizations.  That's easily accomplished with Excel pivot tables.  So far so good.  I now have

```
Question 1:
Suborg 1 35% positive/40% neutral/25% negative
Suborg 2 ...
```

My question though is, once I have these 5 percentages for a given question, can I meaningfully talk about a one suborg being "two standard deviations from the mean" anymore?

At the aggregate level I have 5 averages.  To me it clearly doesn't make sense to talk about the standard deviation with a sample size of 5.  But I don't think I can look at the response rates of the 226 offices either, since the size of the offices varies wildly...

Obviously this kind of analysis is not my everyday gig, so I'm wary of making any claims I can't support...any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a statistics expert, but I taught undergrad a few times.  One rule is that you never average averages.  The standard deviation of a set of averages will be very small and what seems like huge variance (two standard deviations, say)  is really an insignificant effect.